# How to remove text between numbers in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have texts like

```
3.6. Sam
3.7. Willy

4.1. drake
4.2. nadeem
```

I need output like

```
3-6 Sam
3-7 Willy

4-1 drake
4-2 nadeem
```

I tried replace `\d{1}.\d{1}.` with `\d{1}-\d{1}` & later with `$1-$2`

But I cant retain the number. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please check out [column editing](https://www.technipages.com/notepad-column-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.`
- Replace with: `$1-$2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
  (\d+) # group 1, 1 or more digits
  \.    # a dot
  (\d+) # group 2, 1 or more digits
  \.    # a dot
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the following Regex:

```
(\d)\.(\d)\.
```

And replace with:

```
$1-$2
```

You were going wrong because you need capture groups around the numbers. `(\d)` instead of just `\d`.

And you don't need to specify `{1}` if it's just one, you can leave that out. Also you put `.` but that represents any character, not just the period/fullstop, for that you have to escape it with a slash as `\.`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make use of `\K` and use a single group in the replacement.

Find what:

```
\d\K\.(\d)\.
```

Replace with:

```
-$1
```

**Explanation**

- `\d` Match a single digit (use `\d+` to match 1 or more digits)
- `\K`  Reset starting point of the reported match (forget what was matched)
- `\.(\d)\.` Capture a digit in group 1 between matching a dot on the left and right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bi2Frz/1/)

If all your matches are at the start of the string, you prepend a `^` to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A shortest forum of regex will look like this...
Find what: `\.(\d)\.`
Replace with: `-$1`  or  ↝ `-\1`

Comment: I always worry about using a very short and simple regex, I worry that it will change things in other parts of the file. This answer works for the text given, but suppose the file is huge and one of the lines is `4.1. duke has IP address 128.1.2.3.` then that line would be changed to `4-1 duke has IP address 128-12-3`.

Comment: May be he wanted to change ip addresses too, it depends on the question.... Good point ✔♥♥♥♥